"der eine" - implicit "von ihnen"?
I have read/heard the following in https://www.deutsch-perfekt.com/deutsch-hoeren/ein-spezieller-geburtstag:


Warum ist meine Mutter bloß genau an dem Tag geboren, an dem auch die Bundesrepublik Deutschland gegründet wurde? Das macht alles viel komplizierter. Irgendwie muss ich auch das in meine Rede integrieren.​
Ach, Hans-Günther, mach dir mal keine Sorgen. Die meisten Gäste haben von der deutschen Geschichte überhaupt keine Ahnung. Die wissen auch nur: Da wurde ein Staat gegründet. Und mit etwas Glück wissen sie, dass das ja nur der eine war. ​
Westdeutschland, genau!


I don't understand the literal translation of "das ja nur der eine war" to English ("that was only the one"). Did the speaker mean "that was only one of them" (because there was West Germany and East Germany back then) ? If so, would the German excerpt be equal to "das war nur einer von ihnen" ?

Yep, exactly that!

You got it almost correct. In that context, it should be

Das war nur einer von zweien.

Or einer von beiden.
That is because einer von ihnen refers to people primarily and it can be misunderstood easily.
